# Must declare the scalar variable "@Hlava" Must declare the scalar variable "@Vaha"

Tags: sql, sql-server

the code below should outer join 2 declared table but i keep getting the above error....

```
DECLARE @Hlava table 
([Datum/čas] datetime, [Filler L2 Hlava] int)

DECLARE @Vaha table 
([Datum/čas] datetime, [Filler L2 weight] int)

insert into @Hlava ([Datum/čas], [Filler L2 Hlava]) select [DateTime],Value
 from INSQL_LINK.Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory 
 where tagname = 'Filler_L2_hlava' order by datetime desc


 insert into @Vaha ([Datum/čas], [Filler L2 weight]) select [DateTime],Value
 from INSQL_LINK.Runtime.dbo.AnalogHistory 
 where tagname = 'Filler_L2_weight' order by datetime desc

 SELECT [Datum/čas],[Filler L2 Hlava]
FROM @Hlava
FULL OUTER JOIN @Vaha ON @Hlava.[Datum/čas] = @Vaha.[Datum/čas];

 SELECT [Datum/čas],[Filler L2 Hlava]
FROM @Hlava
Union All
 SELECT [Datum/čas],[Filler L2 weight]
FROM @Vaha;
```

why do i need to declare a table as a scalar variable ??

Comment: Are you executing all statements together, or individually?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Please include more details to questions like which DB you are using (SQl server, MS Sql etc). Also it would be better to provide sample input and output so that it would be easy for people tom investigate

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, a table alias cannot begin with `@`.  Hence, your qualified column names don't make sense in a query such as this:

```
SELECT [Datum/čas],[Filler L2 Hlava]
FROM @Hlava FULL OUTER JOIN
     @Vaha
     ON @Hlava.[Datum/čas] = @Vaha.[Datum/čas];
```

So, just given them aliases:

```
SELECT [Datum/čas], [Filler L2 Hlava]
FROM @Hlava h FULL OUTER JOIN
     @Vaha v
     ON h.[Datum/čas] = v.[Datum/čas];
```

I would also recommend that you simplify your column names so they don't have to be escaped.  For instance, `Datum_čas` instead of `Datum/čas`.